# android call same dialog two times

Tags: android, dialog, builder

I'm developing an app and I'm blocked in one simple thing.

In my Activity, I show a dialog (AlertDialog.Builder) that ask a mail address and an activation. These two fields are checked with a Rest API.

If the activation code is wrong I restart the activity (with an Intent) and I show again the dialog.

I don't understand why, if I'm wrong the activation code the first time, the second time appears the dialog correctly, but when I click "submit", the app doesn't run the Rest call and return always "Invalid credentials", like if it would remind the old "state".

Instead, if I run the app and I put the correct credentials, all is ok.

Any idea?

Source code:

```
 public class PinActivity extends Activity {

String mail;
String verification;
JSONObject responseServer;
BluetoothSocket bsocket;
ConnectedThreadBT cdbt;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
EditText mail_add;
EditText verification_code;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);
    setup();

    dialogActivation();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void setup(){
    RestClientManager.initialize(getApplicationContext()).enableDebugLog(true);
    bsocket = BluetoothApplication.getBSocket();
    //salvo codice attivazione sul pacchetto
    cdbt=new ConnectedThreadBT(bsocket,mHandler, "PinActivity");
    cdbt.start();



}


private void dialogActivation(){


    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myDialog));
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_verification, null);
    mail_add = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mailAddress);
    verification_code = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.verification_code);

    builder.setView(view).
            setPositiveButton(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.submit), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                    //prendo e salvo credenziali
                    mail = mail_add.getText().toString();

                    verification = verification_code.getText().toString();
                    //invio dati al server
                    activatePPS();


                }

            });


    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();


}


private void activatePPS(){

    dialogCheck();

    String url = "....";

    RestClientManager.getInstance().makeJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new RequestHandler<>(new RequestCallbacks<JSONObject, Error>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRequestSuccess(JSONObject response)
        {

            responseServer = response;

            int reply_code = 0;
            try {
                reply_code = response.getInt("reply_code");
                checkReplyCode(reply_code);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestError(Error error)
        {

        }




    }, paramsList()));


}

private void dialogCheck(){



    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myDialog));
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_load_check, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();




}

private void checkReplyCode(int reply_code) throws JSONException, IOException {



    switch(reply_code){

        case 0:

            successActivation();

            break;
        case 1001:
            //credenziali invalide
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_credentials), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         

               Intent intent = new Intent(PinActivity.this, PinActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


            break;


    }


}

private void successActivation() throws JSONException {


    String access_token = responseServer.get("access_token").toString();
    String nickname = responseServer.get(".....



    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int value = sharedPref.getInt("step_conf",0);
            if(value==0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MethodCurveActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("style", 0);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }
    },3000);



}

private ArrayMap<String, String> paramsList(){


    ArrayMap<String, String> parameters=new ArrayMap<>();
    parameters.put("user_mail", mail);
    parameters.put(.....

    return parameters;
}

private void resetMobileDevice(){


    String url = "....";



    RestClientManager.getInstance().makeJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new RequestHandler<>(new RequestCallbacks<JSONObject, Error>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRequestSuccess(JSONObject response)
        {

            System.out.println("Risposta:"+response);
            responseServer = response;

            int reply_code = 0;
            try {
                reply_code = response.getInt("reply_code");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                checkReplyCode(reply_code);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestError(Error error)
        {

        }

    }, paramsList()));

}

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {



        }
    }
};

}
```

The important point is in the "case 1001", after error.
I have tried finish() and all the method to delete the old instance of the Activity...

Comment: Hard to advise something without your source code.

Comment: @eleven source code here

Comment: Why exactly you want to restart the activity upon wrong credentials, why don't you just pop up dialog again?

Comment: @AndroidGeek I tried but it has the same behavior. If I pop up the dialog again, and i put the correct credentials, the rest call is not executed and I have immediately the response "Wrong credentials".

Comment: ok, then in my opinion you have a problem with RestClientManager initialization and getting singleton instance of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Application class in your project and initialize RestClientManager in its onCreate Method like this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private final static String LOG_TAG = Application.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Application.onCreate - Initializing application...");
        super.onCreate();
        initializeApplication();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Application.onCreate - Application initialized OK");
    }

    private void initializeApplication() {
        RestClientManager.initialize(getApplicationContext()).enableDebugLog(true);    
    }
}
```

Add this line in your `<Application>` tag in `androidmanifest.xml` file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".App"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

And Make sure your singleton structure should be something like this:

```
    private static RestClientManager instance;

    static void initInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            // Create the instance
            instance = new RestClientManager();
        }
    }

    public static RestClientManager getInstance()
    {
        // Return the instance
        return instance;
    }
```

Remember to remove

```
RestClientManager.initialize(getApplicationContext()).enableDebugLog(true);
```

from your main activity.

Please give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Sorry but RestClientManager is an external Library (https://github.com/julianfalcionelli/SimpleRESTClientHandler), I cannot modify...

Comment: ok then don't modify it, just initialize in Application class

Comment: Ok, I created the Application class. In my Activity it's correct if I call:         RestApplication ra = new RestApplication();?? Because when i run the app, it sees that the restclientmanager is not initialized...

Comment: see my edited post. Add android:name=".MyApp" in your manifest file and then run.

Comment: Sorry, but in my Manifest I have: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">                                                                I have to put android:name=".Myapp" here?

Comment: It not works. Anyway these rest call are inside an Activity that is not the MainActivity...

Comment: It can be a view problem of the dialog?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149718/discussion-between-androidgeek-and-hteo).